# Tried to update a GAN made for graphs to use images, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, tensorflow, generative-adversarial-network

I've been trying to make a GAN in Python based of a article I read a couple of years ago. In the article they made a GAN that was 2D (from: https://blog.paperspace.com/implementing-gans-in-tensorflow/). For the last year or so I've been working on getting it to work for 3D and have not been able to do so. I'm currently feeding the same image to the discriminator as correct in the assumption it will try to exactly copy that image given time. But it only makes images of solid color after a while (first it's all random noise).

I'm sure I'm not getting something, but I can't figure it out. I feel like to problem is with the loss functions and have tried to change them but that has made it better.

The input is as follows:

`iterations` is how many times it should train itself,
`prints` after how many training sessions it should save a file of the result to the system,
`output` after how many training sessions it should output the generator and discriminator loss,
`image` is the file currently in use, in the future this will become a folder with images I want the generator to be able to imitate, but just to see if it works it's now always the same file.

The file I'm currently feeding it is;
[its a square image with half of it black and the other half white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8xJD.png)

I condensed the code to two files for this post -

main.py:

```
import gc
import ganimage

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gc.collect()
    ganimage.run_image_gan(iterations=1000000000, prints=100, output=10, image='D:/myname/Pictures/testfile5.png')
```

ganimage.py:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import trainingData
import os
import datetime
import time
from PIL import Image as pil
import numpy as np

maxvalues = 255
grey_conversion = [.3, .6, .1]


def run_image_gan(iterations, prints, output, image):
    array = image_to_np(image)

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [array.shape[0], array.shape[1], array.shape[2]])
    z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [array.shape[0], array.shape[1], array.shape[2]])

    g_sample = generator(z)

    r_logits, r_rep = discriminator(x)
    f_logits, g_rep = discriminator(g_sample, reuse=True)
    disc_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(r_logits, f_logits))
    gen_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=f_logits, labels=tf.ones_like(f_logits)))

    gen_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope="GAN/Generator")
    disc_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope="GAN/Discriminator")

    gen_step = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(gen_loss,
                                                                       var_list=gen_vars)  # G Train step #0.001
    disc_step = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(disc_loss,
                                                                        var_list=disc_vars)  # D Train step #0.001

    sess = tf.Session()
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run(session=sess)

    start_time = round(time.time(), 1)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    folder = 'D:/myname/Pictures/generated/' + now.strftime("%Y %B %d %Hh%Mm%Ss")
    os.mkdir(folder)

    for i in range(iterations + 1):
        x_batch = image_to_np(image)
        z_batch = trainingData.random_data_img(x_batch)
        _, dloss = sess.run([disc_step, disc_loss], feed_dict={x: x_batch, z: z_batch})
        _, gloss = sess.run([gen_step, gen_loss], feed_dict={z: z_batch})
        g_image = sess.run(g_sample, feed_dict={z: z_batch})

        if i % output == 0:
            print('Iterations: %d\t Discriminator loss: %.20f\t Generator loss: %.20f' % (i, dloss, gloss))

        if i % prints == 0:
            np_to_image(g_image).save(
                folder + '/' + 'iteration_' + str(i) + '_' + str(round(time.time() - start_time, 0)) + 's.png')


def discriminator(x, hsize=[1024, 1024], reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope("GAN/Discriminator", reuse=reuse):
        h1 = tf.layers.dense(x, hsize[0], activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        h2 = tf.layers.dense(h1, hsize[1], activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        h3 = tf.layers.dense(h2, x.shape[2], activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        out = tf.layers.dense(h3, x.shape[2])

    return out, h3


def generator(z, hsize=[1024, 1024], reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope("GAN/Generator", reuse=reuse):
        h1 = tf.layers.dense(z, hsize[0], activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        h2 = tf.layers.dense(h1, hsize[1], activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        h3 = tf.layers.dense(h2, z.shape[2], activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        out = tf.layers.dense(h3, z.shape[2])
    return out


def image_to_np(filename):
    image_array_raw = np.array(pil.open(filename))
    image_array = np.divide(image_array_raw, maxvalues)
    return image_array


def np_to_image(array):
    array_raw = np.multiply(array, maxvalues)
    array_img = np.round(array_raw, 0)
    array_image = array_img.astype('uint8')
    image = pil.fromarray(array_image)
    return image
```

EDIT:
As requested a sample output of a run;

A run of 100 iterations with output and prints at 10 gives this output:

```
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:523: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:524: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:526: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:527: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:532: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
2022-04-17 21:33:32.454448: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 980 major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.291
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 4.00GiB freeMemory: 3.30GiB
2022-04-17 21:33:32.454927: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2022-04-17 21:33:33.802497: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2022-04-17 21:33:33.802763: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0 
2022-04-17 21:33:33.802929: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N 
2022-04-17 21:33:33.803255: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3013 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 980, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.2)
Iterations: 0    Discriminator loss: 0.00040598728810437024  Generator loss: 0.69306391477584838867
Iterations: 10   Discriminator loss: 0.00037987064570188522  Generator loss: 0.69306457042694091797
Iterations: 20   Discriminator loss: 0.00034027246874757111  Generator loss: 0.69306617975234985352
Iterations: 30   Discriminator loss: 0.00028256041696295142  Generator loss: 0.69307404756546020508
Iterations: 40   Discriminator loss: 0.00020526489242911339  Generator loss: 0.69308030605316162109
Iterations: 50   Discriminator loss: 0.00012012914521619678  Generator loss: 0.69308072328567504883
Iterations: 60   Discriminator loss: 0.00004914442615699954  Generator loss: 0.69309645891189575195
Iterations: 70   Discriminator loss: 0.00002701636549318209  Generator loss: 0.69307559728622436523
Iterations: 80   Discriminator loss: 0.00001953361970663536  Generator loss: 0.69310081005096435547
Iterations: 90   Discriminator loss: 0.00001449948649678845  Generator loss: 0.69317066669464111328
Iterations: 100  Discriminator loss: 0.00000890944556886097  Generator loss: 0.69325947761535644531

Process finished with exit code 0
```

And the following images:

[iteration_0_1.0s.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMYit.png)

[iteration_20_1.0s.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjLYP.png)

[iteration_40_1.0s.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjDtJ.png)

[iteration_60_2.0s.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExhaC.png)

[iteration_80_2.0s.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehhmi.png)

[iteration_100_2.0s.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M1Rp.png)

The 2D version would work well, I tried several lines and it would make the same line. For this 3D one I tried letting it run 48 hours once thinking it maybe needed more time, but I always end up with the square completely filled in with the same color.

EDIT2:
This should be copy paste runnable I think;

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import datetime
import time
from PIL import Image as pil
import numpy as np

maxvalues = 255
grey_conversion = [.3, .6, .1]


def run_image_gan(iterations, prints, output, image):
    array = image_to_np(image)

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [array.shape[0], array.shape[1], array.shape[2]])
    z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [array.shape[0], array.shape[1], array.shape[2]])

    g_sample = generator(z)

    r_logits, r_rep = discriminator(x)
    f_logits, g_rep = discriminator(g_sample, reuse=True)
    disc_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(r_logits, f_logits))
    gen_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=f_logits, labels=tf.ones_like(f_logits)))

    gen_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope="GAN/Generator")
    disc_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope="GAN/Discriminator")

    gen_step = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(gen_loss,
                                                                       var_list=gen_vars)  # G Train step #0.001
    disc_step = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(disc_loss,
                                                                        var_list=disc_vars)  # D Train step #0.001

    sess = tf.Session()
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run(session=sess)

    start_time = round(time.time(), 1)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    folder = 'D:/myname/Pictures/generated/' + now.strftime("%Y %B %d %Hh%Mm%Ss")
    os.mkdir(folder)

    for i in range(iterations + 1):
        x_batch = image_to_np(image)
        print('x_batch: ', x_batch)
        np_to_image(x_batch).save(
            folder + '/' + 'iteration_' + str(i) + '_' + str(round(time.time() - start_time, 0)) + 's_x_batch.png')
        z_batch = random_data_img(x_batch)
        print('z_batch: ', z_batch)
        np_to_image(z_batch).save(
            folder + '/' + 'iteration_' + str(i) + '_' + str(round(time.time() - start_time, 0)) + 's_z_batch.png')
        _, dloss = sess.run([disc_step, disc_loss], feed_dict={x: x_batch, z: z_batch})
        _, gloss = sess.run([gen_step, gen_loss], feed_dict={z: z_batch})
        g_image = sess.run(g_sample, feed_dict={z: z_batch})

        if i % output == 0:
            print('Iterations: %d\t Discriminator loss: %.20f\t Generator loss: %.20f' % (i, dloss, gloss))

        if i % prints == 0:
            np_to_image(g_image).save(
                folder + '/' + 'iteration_' + str(i) + '_' + str(round(time.time() - start_time, 0)) + 's.png')


def discriminator(x, hsize=[1024, 1024], reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope("GAN/Discriminator", reuse=reuse):
        h1 = tf.layers.dense(x, hsize[0], activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        h2 = tf.layers.dense(h1, hsize[1], activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        h3 = tf.layers.dense(h2, x.shape[2], activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        out = tf.layers.dense(h3, x.shape[2])

    return out, h3


def generator(z, hsize=[1024, 1024], reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope("GAN/Generator", reuse=reuse):
        h1 = tf.layers.dense(z, hsize[0], activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        h2 = tf.layers.dense(h1, hsize[1], activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        h3 = tf.layers.dense(h2, z.shape[2], activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        out = tf.layers.dense(h3, z.shape[2])
    return out


def image_to_np(filename):
    image_array_raw = np.array(pil.open(filename))
    image_array = np.divide(image_array_raw, maxvalues)
    return image_array


def np_to_image(array):
    array_raw = np.multiply(array, maxvalues)
    array_img = np.round(array_raw, 0)
    array_image = array_img.astype('uint8')
    image = pil.fromarray(array_image)
    return image

def random_data_img(image):
    data = np.random.rand(image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2])
    return np.array(data)
```

EDIT3:
@Karan, you are a saint for helping as you are doing! Sadly, still can't get it to fully work. This is where I'm at;

main:

```
import gc
import ganimage

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gc.collect()
    ganimage.run_image_gan(iterations=1000000, prints=10000, output=1000, batch_size=100, image='D:/myname/Pictures/testfile5.png')
```

ganimage:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import datetime
import time
from PIL import Image as pil
import numpy as np

maxvalues = 255
grey_conversion = [.3, .6, .1]


def run_image_gan(iterations, prints, output, batch_size, image):
    image_to_array = image_to_np(image)

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                       [batch_size, image_to_array.shape[0], image_to_array.shape[1], image_to_array.shape[2]])
    z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                       [batch_size, image_to_array.shape[0], image_to_array.shape[1], image_to_array.shape[2]])

    g_sample = generator(z)

    r_logits, r_rep = discriminator(x)
    f_logits, g_rep = discriminator(g_sample, reuse=True)
    disc_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(r_logits, f_logits))
    gen_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=f_logits, labels=tf.ones_like(f_logits)))

    gen_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope="GAN/Generator")
    disc_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope="GAN/Discriminator")

    gen_step = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(gen_loss,
                                                                       var_list=gen_vars)  # G Train step #0.001
    disc_step = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(disc_loss,
                                                                        var_list=disc_vars)  # D Train step #0.001

    sess = tf.Session()
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run(session=sess)

    start_time = round(time.time(), 1)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    folder = 'D:/myname/Pictures/generated/' + now.strftime("%Y %B %d %Hh%Mm%Ss")
    os.mkdir(folder)

    for i in range(iterations + 1):
        x_batch = []
        z_batch = []
        for j in range(batch_size):
            x_batch.append(np.array(image_to_np(image)))
            z_batch.append(np.array(random_data_img(image_to_np(image))))
        _, dloss = sess.run([disc_step, disc_loss], feed_dict={x: x_batch, z: z_batch})
        _, gloss = sess.run([gen_step, gen_loss], feed_dict={z: z_batch})
        g_image = sess.run(g_sample, feed_dict={z: z_batch})

        if i % output == 0:
            print('Iterations: %d\t Discriminator loss: %.20f\t Generator loss: %.20f' % (i, dloss, gloss))

        if i % prints == 0:
            for j in range(g_image.shape[0]):
                np_to_image(g_image[j, :]).save(folder + '/' + 'iteration_' + str(i) + '_nr_' + str(j + 1) + '_' + str(
                    round(time.time() - start_time, 0)) + 's.png')


def discriminator(x, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope("GAN/Discriminator", reuse=reuse):
        h1 = tf.layers.conv2d(x, 64, [3, 3], activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        h2 = tf.layers.conv2d(h1, 64, [3, 3], activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        h3 = tf.math.reduce_mean(h2, 1)
        h3 = tf.math.reduce_mean(h3, 1)
        out = tf.layers.dense(h3, 1)

    return out, h3


def generator(z, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope("GAN/Generator", reuse=reuse):
        h1 = tf.layers.conv2d(z, 64, [3, 3], activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        h2 = tf.layers.conv2d(h1, 64, [3, 3], activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        out = tf.layers.dense(h2, z.shape[-1])
    return out


def image_to_np(filename):
    image_array_raw = np.array(pil.open(filename))
    image_array = np.divide(image_array_raw, maxvalues)
    return image_array


def np_to_image(array):
    array_raw = np.multiply(array, maxvalues)
    array_img = np.round(array_raw, 0)
    array_image = array_img.astype('uint8')
    image = pil.fromarray(array_image)
    return image


def random_data_img(image):
    data = np.random.rand(image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2])
    return np.array(data)
```

Comment: hi, Is your code working upto the mark on 2D images? Can you please share some training logs, information related to the data? The code seems to be fine IMO

Comment: @KaranDhingra: I've edited a sample output into the post. :)

Comment: Can you please share the shape of z_batch. I guess you might need to make few changes in the generator pipeline.

Comment: This is where that comes from, and has the same shape as the image delivered; 

`def random_data_img(image):
    data = np.random.rand(image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2])
    return np.array(data)`

Comment: Can you print the shape of x_batch and z_batch, i guess the batch only contains a single image. Or the input is a b/w image.

Comment: You are correct, x_batch is the input image and z_batch is a single image of noise that changes every iteration. I added that it prints both of them every iteration, and x_batch is just the input image everytime and z_batch one image of random noise. I've edited the version that does that into the post above, and also made it so that by pasting the two files you should be able to run them as is. (maybe change the directory, I guess.)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information, I believe you would need to

1. increase the batch size or atleast introduce the concept of samples/batch in your code.
2. Currently your generator is taking an input of shape `[X, y, 3]` (for example) and returning `[64, 64, 3]`. It processes each spatial location independently, so i believe you should use convolutional layers to model spatial relations.

   ```
   def generator(z, hsize=[1024, 1024], reuse=False):
        with tf.variable_scope("GAN/Generator", reuse=reuse):
            h1 = tf.layers.conv2d(z, 64, [3, 3], activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
            h2 = tf.layers.conv2d(h1, 64, [3, 3], activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
            out = tf.layers.dense(h3, z.shape[-1])
        return out
   ```
3. Similarly discriminator should have an output of [X_batch, 1] (where X_batch are the number of samples as input to network). We can also have Convolutional neural network again for spatial correlation

   ```
   def discriminator(z, hsize=[1024, 1024], reuse=False):
        with tf.variable_scope("GAN/Discriminator", reuse=reuse):
            h1 = tf.layers.conv2d(z, 64, [3, 3], activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
            h2 = tf.layers.conv2d(h1, 64, [3, 3], activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
            h3 = tf.math.reduce_mean(h2, 1)
            h3 = tf.math.reduce_mean(h3, 1)
            out = tf.layers.dense(h3, 1)
        return out
   ```

The purpose of reduce_mean is to club together the response over length and breadth of input image so that the output is [X_batch, 1] while it takes [X_batch, L, B, H] as input

You would also need to replace the x, z placeholder with

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, array.shape[0], array.shape[1], array.shape[2]])
# Added additional None which specifies number of samples in both x and z
z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, array.shape[0], array.shape[1], array.shape[2]])
```

The above code changes should work, but you might have to make certain changes as i have not worked with Tensorflow 1.X in a very long time.

Comment: It took me a little while to implement this, sadly it still makes squares of a solid color after learning for a while. :( I've added the code in the post above as an edit. Something more is going on. what I do notice is that the generator loss stays pretty stable around 0.69 and the discriminator loss super low in the 0.000somenumber range. I feel like they are not really getting better b/c they seem to be happy where they are. If you have a way to do this in V2+ I'd also be down to try that :)

Comment: hey, the generator and discriminator are still dense layers; it means that response of discriminator is averaged over all the pixels; please make sure that output of discriminator only contains batch and linear features (ideally under original GAN the output needs to be [batch_size, 1])